# When List<T> resizes, how much additional capacity is added?

Tags: .net

When a List resizes because there is no more excess capacity, how much capacity is added?  just 1?  Or does it add Capacity (so doubling the total capacity)?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for responding so quickly!  I should have thought to use reflector.  I wish I could accept multiple answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The capacity will double.

This is controlled by the following source:

```
// Ensures that the capacity of this list is at least the given minimum
// value. If the currect capacity of the list is less than min, the
// capacity is increased to twice the current capacity or to min, 
// whichever is larger.
private void EnsureCapacity(int min) { 
    if (_items.Length < min) { 
        int newCapacity = _items.Length == 0? _defaultCapacity : _items.Length * 2;
        if (newCapacity < min) newCapacity = min; 
        Capacity = newCapacity;
    }
}
```

`_defaultCapacity` is a `const int` equal to `4`.

Answer (score 4):

This is the EnsureCpacity methods as reflector sees it. The size will double :)

```
private void EnsureCapacity(int min)
{
    if (this._items.Length < min)
    {
        int num = (this._items.Length == 0) ? 4 : (this._items.Length * 2);
        if (num < min)
        {
            num = min;
        }
        this.Capacity = num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it doubles, based on the following code:

```
int initialCapacity = 100;
List<string> list = new List<string>(initialCapacity);

Console.WriteLine(list.Capacity);

for(int i = 0; i < list.Capacity; i++){
    list.Add("string " + i);    
}

list.Add("another string");

Console.WriteLine(list.Capacity); // shows 200, changes based on initialCapacity
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally double.